# Notation: What does $[0,1]^2 \backslash [0,0.5]^2 $ mean?

Tags: calculus, notation

The context of the of the problem is computing a integral in two variables. So I guess: $[0,1]^2  \backslash [0,0.5]^2 = (0.5,1] \times (0.5,1] $

But I wonder, why one has just not written the latter from the beginning.. not everyone is so secure to just use definitions / notation without worries.
I hope someone knows this and can clarify this.

(The only other place I have seen this notation, was in Python :P )

Comment: Hint: Consider the point $P=(.3,.8)$. Decide whether $P$ is in $[0,1]^2$, in $[0,0.5]^2$, in $(0.5,1] \times (0.5,1]$.

Comment: No it should be the union of three squares, think about it.

Comment: Graphically, this is the unit square (with sides $[0,1]$) with the bottom left corner removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means
$$
[0,1] \times [0,1] \setminus [0, 0.5] \times [0, 0.5]
$$
where the $\setminus$ means the difference between sets.

[image: the situation] 
([Large version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF7Xz.png))

The bluish big square is $[0,1]^2$ and the redish small one $[0,0.5]^2$.
The set difference is that upside down $L$. 
The inner sides (top side of red and right side of red) are removed, so
there the boundary of the difference is open.

BTW: $(0.5,1]^2$ is the greenishish upper right small square, with left and lower sides open.

Comment: You could *at least* explain that this is not equal to $(0.5,1]^2$... OP seems to be confused about this and I'm not sure your answer really helps.

Comment: I am preparing an image right now.

Comment: And why did you post your answer before it was complete?

Comment: I did not expect the Spanish inquisition.

Comment: I'm trying to make the point that being the "fastest gun in the west" is less important than posting complete answers.

Comment: I am into Kaizen (the art of incremental improvements). My posts suffer lots of edits.

Comment: So do mine, but I at least try to post a complete answer as a first attempt... But I can see this discussion isn't leading anywhere useful.

Comment: Nah, nothing against good critique.

Answer (score 2):

$[0,1]^2$ is the unit square, while $[0, 0.5]^2$ is the quarter of the square that includes the corner at the origin.  So $[0,1]^2\setminus[0,0.5]^2$ is the other three-fourths of the square, a (roughly) ell-shaped region (or exactly the shape of the L-tromino).  This is distinct from what you've written, $(0.5, 1]\times (0.5, 1]$, which would be $([0,1]\setminus[0,0.5])^2$ — this is exactly like saying that $a^2-b^2$ isn't the same as $(a-b)^2$ in algebra.